# Implement pagination on Vuetify v-data-table and v-data-footer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have elaborated a solution to have pagination with continuation tokens on a v-data-table but I have arrived to a dead end. I'm using Vuetify 2.5.6 and cannot migrate to version 3

I have a data-table like the one below. I have a vuex store that before the table component is loaded has the next continuation token from an Azure function, the total numbers of elements in the database (that substitutes the totalItems from the footer in the second template from the bottom) and finally, I was trying to enable the next button based on the existance of the continuation token. Apart, I would need to implement a function in such button to make a call back to the Azure funtion to retrieve the next page.

The solution so far reads from the parent component the page and then is displayed in this table component, but I don't see a way to enable the next button depending on the existance of the continuation token, or more broadly, how to configure the next button to make calls. I'm afraid my knowledge on this area is not that wide.

Can someone tell me how to change the properties of the next button based on the component data? Thanks

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    class="tableContent"
    :headers="header"
    :items="data"
    sort-by="email"
    :id="pagetableStyle"
    :footer-props="{
      'items-per-page-options': [10]
      //'pagination': {
      //  'itemsLength': 10
      //}
    }"
    :items-per-page="10"
  >
    <template
      v-slot:top
      v-if="tableToolbarButtons !== undefined && tableName !== undefined"
    >
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-toolbar-title :v-if="tableName" class="tableNameStyle">{{
          tableName
        }}</v-toolbar-title>

        <template :v-if="tableToolbarButtons">
          <div v-for="(item, index) in tableToolbarButtons" :key="index">
            <v-btn
              class="button"
              color="primary"
              v-on:click="item.clickButton"
              dark
            >
              <v-icon>
                {{ item.icon }}
              </v-icon>
              {{ item.name }}
            </v-btn>
          </div>
        </template>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.deleteItem`]="{ item }" v-if="customDelete">
      <div v-for="(deleteItem, index) in customDelete" :key="index">
        <v-icon small @click="deleteItem.clickButton(data.indexOf(item))">
          {{ deleteItem.icon }}</v-icon
        >
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
      <div v-for="(actionItem, index) in customActions" :key="index">
        {{ item.user }}
        <v-icon small @click="actionItem.clickButton(data.indexOf(item))">
          {{ actionItem.icon }}</v-icon
        >
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.requestedActions`]="{ item }">
      <div
        v-for="(requestItem, index) in requestedActions"
        :key="index"
        class="selectStyle"
      >
        <Select
          :selectedValue="item.status"
          :items="requestItem.selectItems"
          @onChangeSelectedValue="
            requestItem.clickButton(data.indexOf(item), item)
          "
          styleName="adminSelect"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.accessListActions`]="{ item }">
      <div
        v-for="(accesItem, index) in accessListActions"
        :key="index"
        class="selectStyle"
      >
        <Button
          buttonName="Remove"
          @onClickButton="accesItem.clickButton(data.indexOf(item), item)"
          styleName="button"
        />
      </div>
    </template>
    <template #footer.page-text="props">
      {{props.pageStart}}-{{props.pageStop}} of {{itemsCount}}
    </template>
    <template v-if="getContToken() != false" #footer.next-icon="{nexticon}" >
      {{nexticon.disabled=false}}
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
import Select from "../Select.vue";
import Button from "../Button.vue";
import store from "../../store/store";
export default {
  name: "PageTable",
  props: {
    tableName: { typeof: String, require: true },
    header: { typeof: Array, require: true },
    data: { typeof: Array, require: true },
    pagetableStyle: { typeof: String, require: true },
    tableToolbarButtons: { typeof: Array, require: false },
    customActions: { typeof: Array, require: false },
    customDelete: { typeof: Array, require: false },
    requestedActions: { typeof: Array, require: false },
    accessListActions: { typeof: Array, require: false },
  },
  components: {
    Select: Select,
    Button: Button,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      itemsCount: this.getLogEventsCount()
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getLogEventsCount() {
      if (!(store.getters.getLogEventsCount == null) && !(store.getters.getLogEventsCount == undefined)) {
        return store.getters.getLogEventsCount;
    }
    else {
      return 0;
    }
    },
    getContToken() {
      if (!(store.getters.getCompositeToken == null) && !(store.getters.getCompositeToken == undefined)) {
        return store.getters.getCompositeToken;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
    }    
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#start {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#end {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
#activityLog {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#tableContent {
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.v-btn > .v-btn__content .v-icon {
  color: inherit;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: none;
}
.v-btn > .v-btn__content {
  text-transform: none;
}
.button {
  background-color: #616e7c !important;
  margin-right: 32px;
  width: 127px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid
    rgba(97.00000181794167, 110.00000104308128, 124.00000020861626, 1);
  border-radius: 64px;
}
.selectStyle {
  height: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
}
.v-data-table ::v-deep .v-application ::v-deep .primary--text,
.v-application ::v-deep .primary--text {
  color: #fff !important;
}
.tableNameStyle {
  display: block;
  height: 72px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 72px;
  color: #3e4c59;
  margin-right: 32px;
}
#tableContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.v-input__slot {
  min-height: 0px;
}
.v-data-table ::v-deep .v-data-table__wrapper {
  overflow: unset;
}

.v-application .primary {
  background-color: #616e7c !important;
}

.selectStyle {
  margin-top: -14px;
}

.theme--dark.v-text-field--solo > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot {
  width: 144px;
}

.theme--dark.v-btn.v-btn--has-bg {
  text-transform: none;
}

.selectStyle >>> .v-btn:not(.v-btn--round).v-size--default[data-v-015de462] {
  text-transform: none;
}
.tableContent ::v-deep thead tr th span {
  color: #9aa5b1;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.tableContent {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
.tableContent
  ::v-deep
  .v-text-field.v-text-field--solo:not(.v-text-field--solo-flat)
  > .v-input__control
  > .v-input__slot,
.tableContent ::v-deep.v-btn--is-elevated {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tableContent ::v-deep .v-data-footer {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
#table > .v-data-footer .v-icon {
  disabled: false;
}
.tableContent ::v-deep tbody tr td {
  height: 62px !important;
}
.v-btn__content {
  text-transform: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the hide-default-header and hide-default-footer props to remove the default header and footer respectively.

```html
 <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    hide-default-header
    hide-default-footer
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
```

and implement a new footer

```html
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" hide-default-footer class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:footer>
             <v-btn @click="les()">
                -
              </v-btn>
           <v-btn @click="getContToken()">
                +
              </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: That's one solution. But still, I cannot believe it is not possible to set manually the next or previous icons to enabled. Am I using a wrong template? Syntaxis?